# How to escape '-' in SpEL in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-el

In my Spring Controller I set following to my model attribute:

```
model.addAttribute("abc-def", "Hello World");
```

In my thymeleaf html I want to read the value of `abc-def`.

```
<th:block th:text="${abc-def}"></th:block>
```

But I get the error:

```
The operator 'SUBTRACT' is not supported between objects of type 'null' and 'null'
```

Its clear because `-` is an arithmetic operator. **Is there a way to escape `-` for reading out the model value?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My advice would be: don't use variables names with dashes in them.  (Would you try to define a variable `int abc-def = 5;` in java?)

In any case, this seems to work if you have to use it:

```
<th:block th:text="${#request.getAttribute('abc-def')}" />
```

Comment: yeah, I wouldnt create a variable like that. Just asked because it would be comfortable because the data comes directly from the DB without changing something. At the end, I replace `-` with `_`.

Comment: You could also put all your database variables in a map -- then access them like this: `${db['abc-def']}` or `${db.get('abd-def')}`.  So you can avoid collisions with your regular model variables.

Answer (score 1):

### Thymeleaf 2

Per the [Expression Basic Objects](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-basic-objects) section of the documentation (with more details in [Appendix A](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-a-expression-basic-objects)), the context variables are in a `#vars` object. So, you can access variables with something like this:

```
<th:block th:text="${#vars.get('abc-def')}" />
```

### Thymeleaf 3

As Metroids commented this all changes in Thymeleaf 3. [It combines the `#ctx` and `#vars` objects](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-a-expression-basic-objects), so you need to use the [Context's getVariable](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.7.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/context/IContext.html#getVariable-java.lang.String-) method:

```
<th:block th:text="${#ctx.getVariable('abc-def')}" />
```

### But this isn't the best plan

While certainly these will "work", having variables with punctuation in them is a bit unusual, and may confuse the next programmer to see your code. I wouldn't do it unless I had a really good reason to use that name.

Comment: Note that this syntax changes from thymeleaf 2 to 3 -- it's been renamed to `${#vars.getVariable('abc-def')}` in thymeleaf 3.